# How to derate a relay switiching for a capactive load

Tags: relay, dc

How do I derate this graph for the switching contact of this [relay](https://docs.rs-online.com/6277/0900766b814f02dd.pdf)? The contact spec is 48V DC at 1.8A. From the graph below the Max DC load for 1.8A is 90V DC, so I do derate this for a capacitive load?

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7YUZ8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: For capacitive loads the inrush current ratings of the contacts need to be considered, because a capacitor is nothing different than a short when it is empty. Not all the relays (including yours) are inrush type, so there's no way to de-rate a graph directly for capacitive loads.

Comment: @RohatKılıç the load is a DC/DC switchmode power supply. Which I assume is a capacitive load.

Comment: I understand. Anything having large input capacitors (e.g. at least tens of microfarads) can be considered as capacitive loads. As I stated in my comment, you can't just directly relate a contact ratings graph to capacitive loads. If you are to use a relay for turning on and off the converter, you need to use either an electronic switch (i.e. SSR or MOSFET) or an inrush type relay. Yours is not an inrush type relay, and thus does not have inrush ratings for the contacts. Inrush type relays can be thought as relays designed for capacitive loads.

Answer (score 1):

Derating is not the solution. The solution is to limit the current, which can be done by adding some resistance in series to limit the current to within the ratings of the relay contacts. You can do so in one of two ways:

1. Permanently
2. At the start

**Permanently**:
You can add an ICL ([Inrush Current Limiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current_limiter)) or even a low value resistor

**At the start**:
Use [precharge](http://liionbms.com/php/precharge.php) (my site) to charge the capacitors slowly before turning on the main contactor (relay).

Comment: So the circuit I included in my question now, will be okay?

Comment: I have added a button with a 10 ohm 100W resistor as an example.

Comment: I like it!..............

Comment: How do I choose the precharge time. In your case you gave an example of 500ms? So I can calculate a better R1. A 100W resistor is a bit to expensive for me

Comment: In my industry (automotive) it's how long the driver is willing to wait. Half a second is fine. I don't know about your industry.

Comment: By driver are you referring to U3 in my case?

Comment: No "driver" as in "the human being behind the steering wheel of a car".

Comment: lol, this is an electronic site, you cannot blame me for that error in misunderstanding...

Comment: I calculated a resistance of 500 ohm at 5W, based on the caps at 400uF and 1 second precharge time. However at 500 ohm I will 96mA at the DC/DC which is not enough to turn on U3, so the relay will never engage. U3 needs atleast 1.2A but then gives me a precharge time of 50ms, which is way to fast. So how do I solve this because your site does not take into account the current needed to turn on the device that activates the relay

Comment: OK, so go lower. My go-to value is 10 Ohm.

Comment: I am confused. Isnt the whole point of the resistor is to lengthen the charge time of the caps using T=R*C*5. Which for a 10ohm is 20ms.